# Simulated secondary click doesn't work | Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: firefox

I would like to know how I can use simulated secondary click by press for a few seconds click left. Because it doesn't work now.

I have turn on accessibility option in Settings->Accessibility menu : Simulated Secondary click.

But on the desktop, doesn't work. I would succeed because its important for me to navigate on browser (Firefox/Chromium) with simulated secondary click.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: 
System settings... -> Universal Access -> Pointing and Clicking.
Turn on Simulated Secondary Click.

[image: simulate secondary click]

Then, when you hold down your left mouse button for some time and release it, right mouse button click will be triggered.

If you hold your mouse over text, a "progress bar" is drawn under your cursor.